# Expected value of a product of function and stochastic integral that depend on a solution of SDE

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $X_t$ be the solution of the SDE
$$ dX_t=f(t,X_t)dt+\sigma(X_t)dW_t.$$
I need to check if
$$ \mathbb{E}\biggl[(\sigma(X_t)+\sigma(X_a))\int_a^t\sigma'(X_s)\sigma(X_s)dW_s\biggr]=0.$$
If this is not the case, it is enough for me to prove that it is equal to $\mathcal{O}(t-a)$ if possible.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using $$\Bbb E\left[\int_a^t u(X_s)dW_s\right]=0 \tag1$$ and $$\Bbb E\left[\int_a^t u(X_s)dW_s\int_a^t v(X_s)dW_s\right]=\int_a^bu(X_s)v(X_s)ds \tag2$$ together with
$$
σ(X_t)-σ(X_a)=\int_a^t\left(σ'(X_s)f(s,X_s)+\tfrac12σ''(X_s)σ(X_s)^2\right)\,ds + \int_a^tσ'(X_s)σ(X_s)\,dW_s \tag3
$$
it follows that the non-zero terms are for the given expectation are,
$$
\int_t^a\Bbb E\left[σ'(X_s)^2σ(X_s)^2\right]\,ds,\tag4
$$
so no, its value is not zero. And yes, provided the integrand is bounded you get that it is $O(t-a)$.

Comment: But note that we have $\sigma(X_t)+\sigma(X_a)$ and not $\sigma(X_t)-\sigma(X_a)$.

Comment: Yes, but the difference has expectation zero using the first rule, as $σ(X_a)$ is a constant in this situation.

Comment: But $\sigma(X_a)$ is still a random variable. If it is independent of $\int_a^t\sigma'(X_s)\sigma(X_s)dW_s$ then we write $\sigma(X_t)+\sigma(X_a)=\sigma(X_t)-\sigma(X_a)+2\sigma(X_a)$ and the last term vanishes by independence, this is what you mean?
If so, how can we make sure of this independence?

Comment: Yes. The independence is a result of the filtration and that $W$ is a martingale. The increments of $W$ for times above $a$ are independent of $X_a$ resp. all the history up to tim $a$.

Comment: I see, thank you!